# matplotlib: plot milliseconds time series in human readable format

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-science

I have a list of integers representing a time series in milliseconds. Each value was obtained by calling `int(time.time() * 1000)` and appending to the list.

Now I would like to **make a plot using matplotlib that will display the milliseconds time series on the x-axis in the format `"%H:%M:%S"`.**

I tried using these values along with a matplotlib data formatter by setting: `plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S"))`
but I got the following error when attempting to plot: *OverflowError: int too big to convert*.

I have also tried using already preformatted time series values as strings by calling `time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(time.time()))` and appending to the list instead with no luck, resulting in this problem: *Using categorical units to plot a list of strings that are all parsable as floats or dates. If these strings should be plotted as numbers, cast to the appropriate data type before plotting.*

Could anyone please help me to plot milliseconds in a human readable format on the x-axis?

Comment: The millisecond format would be `%H:%M:%S.%f"`.

Comment: @Mr.T OP doesn't want to show milliseconds, the issue is the error when using a `DataFormatter` with millisecond values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert time values (which are ms since epoch in UTC) using [`epoch2num`](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.epoch2num). Then you can use the standard `DateFormatter`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import time

now_ms = int(time.time() * 1000)
x = [now_ms+t for t in range(0,10_000,1000)]

plt.plot([mpl.dates.epoch2num(t/1000) for t in x], range(10))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.dates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S"))
```

You should use matplotlib [version 3.3.1 or newer](https://matplotlib.org/api/api_changes.html#api-changes-for-3-3-1).

Comment: Please don’t use epoch2num.  It will be deprecated.

Comment: @JodyKlymak: can you give a link to some documentation stating that `epoch2num` will be deprecated?

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/17983

Comment: @JodyKlymak ehm sorry, this is about **un**deprecating `epoch2num` and it refers to exactly the same as the link I included in the answer.

Comment: Yes, but it still *will* be deprecated.  We un-deprecated because unbeknownst to us pandas was directly using this method.  The point being that a) the method is ill-named (it should be `unixtime2num`), b) the user would ideally not be converting to our internal representation of time (float days since epoch) c) datetime tools have evolved to the point where users can rely on those, rather than matplotlib having its own parallel set of datetime manipulations.

Comment: @JodyKlymak Thanks for the details. Maybe this reasoning should be included in the official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do is just convert to datetime64 as:

```py
now_ms = int(time.time() * 1000)
x = now_ms+np.arange(0,10_000,1000)
x = x.astype('datetim64[ms]')
plt.plot(x, range(10))
```